# Yii sessions storage and expire flow

Tags: php, session, yii, expired-sessions

Currently sessions are stored in a database table. Of course they have an expire timestamp. I wonder, when a sessions reaches it's expirationdate, will the record also be deleted from the database? I cannot find that particular info in the Yii-docs.

Answer (score 1):

The records will delete. You can check it [HERE](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.16/framework/web/CDbHttpSession.php#L292). Methods calls from [THIS row](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.16/framework/web/CHttpSession.php#L112). But if you need you can override class for sessions and use your custom logic.